# Secure image downloading

Tags: php, security, file

I have been researching securely uploading images, and it has become apparent that actually serving the images is where most of the risk is for rogue PHP files that could compromise the server.

Many are suggesting that having a image processing script e.g getimage.php?i=575748 which would lookup in the database 575748 and actually return myphoto.jpg (whithout the user knowing the location of the origional image) is much more secure.

Can any point me in the right direction of what sort of things I should be implementing in the script? I know setting the content type headers is a must, but is this enough to stop code executing?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are images on your server even executable? IE why is the PHP user (nobody or apache most likely) have executable privileges on files with an image extension?

Comment: Currently they are not, however I want to eliminate the risk of the user being able to change the file extension to say.php and then execute it. I figured by delivering images via a script, they have no way of knowing where the file is stored, and as such would make it much more difficult to access it directly?

Comment: If you're worried about bad images entering the system, run [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) on the image before it's stored. This will return false if the file is not actually an image.

Comment: @anjunatl One issue with that is that a file can be an image and another format at the same time. For example there is an infamous gif that's a jar at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and it has become apparent that actually serving the images is where
>   most of the risk is for rogue PHP files that could compromise the
>   server

This only happens if two conditions are met:

- You allow uploading of non-image files
- Downloading is done through a direct link

Thwart one of these and the danger disappears. Of course closing both is better.

The database solution aims at disrupting condition #2, but you can also check, when uploading the image, that it is indeed an image using the `getImageSize()` function. Or trying to load the image with `imageCreateFromJPEG()` or other appropriate function.

If the object loaded is not an image, just display "Sorry, image is corrupt". This both protects your users against uploading broken images and you against someone uploading a rogue PHP file (or maybe a copyrighted video or cracked executable or...).

**UPDATE**: you can also obfuscate an already existing upload-and-download facility:

Say that currently you upload the user image, assign to it a unique ID, save it as `./images/UNIQUEID.jpg`, and serve to the user `http://www.yoursite.com/images/UNIQUEID.jpg` as URL.

- You apply a `.htaccess` so that access to `./images/whatever` is redirected to `./images/index.php?ID=whatever`
- You create a `index.php` script that takes "whatever", extracts the image ID, and outputs the image.

All old URLs will continue to work and *appear* to directly load the image, but what they're actually doing is invoke a PHP script that checks for the image and sends it along as a bytestream, without interpreting.

You'll want to be setting `ETag` to the ID, `Last-Modified` to `file_mtime()` of the image file, and `Content-Length` to the file size. Also, you may want to check the incoming header `If-Modified-Since` and `If-None-Match`: if the date of the file corresponds to IMS or the IFN value corresponds to the ID, you can send a `HTTP/304 Not Modified` answer instead of the image, saving considerable bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Put the upload folder outside the root folder (i.e. outside the /www/ or /htdocs/ or /httpdocs/ folder) for one thing. Set permissions on the folder so only the local user can write to it.

As for the database idea, you could definitely go ahead and do that in conjunction with the above mentioned ideas, should make for a fairly secure image uploader service.

The only risks involved are when you don't set the right permissions on the folder that you're going to upload to, which indeed could compromise the server.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I see. You could also store the images in a database if you do not want to have them floating around your file system. Whichever way you prefer. The problem with having scripts serve images instead of Apache is that the image has to be loaded into memory. So be prepared for performance repercussions.

Comment: Storing images in the database is most often the wrong choice. Images don't have to be "loaded into memory" to serve them.

Comment: @MarcusAdams My impression was that you do unless you use the sendfile mod for apache. http://www.jasny.net/articles/how-i-php-x-sendfile/

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your original security concern, run [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) on the image before it is stored - throw it away if you get `false` out of that function. (If anyone knows of a better solution to preventing bad "images" from coming through, I'm all ears!)

Store the images on the filesystem outside of the web-accessible directories. Using the table of key to physical location is a good idea. Store the `IMAGETYPE_XXX` value with it (it's the 2nd index of the array returned by `getimagesize()`) and switch on that to serve up the image using [imagejpeg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php), [imagepng()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php), etc. Don't forget to set your Content-type header when you do.

Comment: Actually he can just `readfile` the images with the correct header, there's no need of loading the images again. Even if this approach can be very useful to serve the image at different resolutions (thumbnail, comp, full image, etc.) or applying watermarks.